# Notify when AMI available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

anyone know how to synchronously call AWS Lambda when my new AMI is available? I'd like emphasize that I'm interested in AMI's available state, not just pending. Basically I'm looking for something like RDS Event for EC2.

> Flow: CreateAMIAPICall --> AMI ami-abc123 is beeing created (pending) --> AMI ami-abc123 is available --> ? --> TRIGGER AWS LAMBDA

Comment: your question is little confusing, can you add more detail?

Comment: @Bhavesh like now?

Comment: Your question makes perfect sense.  You are creating an AMI using a tool like Packer and you would like a Lambda event to trigger when the AMI is ready to use

Answer (score 2):

You did not state the language you are using in Lambda, but `boto3` has the capability!

From [EC2 — Boto 3 Docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.ImageAvailable):

```
waiter = client.get_waiter('image_available')
```

> Polls `EC2.Client.describe_images()` every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

Comment: I stick to nodeJS. AFAIK there is no such an "waiter" there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an event type like this which is generated when [CreateImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateImage.html) is called and subsequently a new AMI becomes ready to use

You'll just have to poll for the state with [DescribeImages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know there is no such an event. Anyway I have intention to provoke some brainstorming which will show what are community ideas about that. The non-obvious solutions.

Comment: Amazon official AMIs have a notification on a SNS topic.  Presumably they run a poller and then use this to push the notifications