# Terraform, Autoscaling listen for new AMI, and deploy automatically

Tags: terraform, packer

I currently use the Hashicorp products extensively, within the AWS ecosystem using the philosophies of 'Immutable Microservices'.

In simple terms, my current workflow involves building an AMI using packer, and then using terraform to deploy. My Terraform script makes use of an autoscaling policy, that picks up the latest AMI version and provisions accordingly.

I was wondering if there is a method within the Terraform suite, to Automatically listen for a new AMI version, and then provision, without having to execute `Terraform Apply`? I am trying to achieve something where the packer script builds a new AMI, and this triggers hardware provisioned under the old image to be wound-down and replaced by new hardware based off the new AMI.

Comment: Terraform is a tool for provisioning infrastructure. What you're asking for sounds like an orchestrator. You have a bunch of options around this including hooking into CI/CD systems through to Lambda functions. Most of these can be either ran based on a change happening or just rely on Terraform's natural idempotency to be continuously ran and let Terraform handle things when the AMI changes. Unfortunately this feels more like a tools recommendation question right now so is off topic. If you could narrow the question then it may be possible to answer usefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it through Terraform, but the relying mechanism would be a Custom Lambda Function. Besides describing and getting the latest successful image, you need to handle the 'clone the TF repo, do the replacement variable where needed and execute' parts. Also make sure this is super heavy well tested, because once you run Terraform you want only expected behavior :)

[Boto3 Describe Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704471/notify-when-ami-available)